# How does the "random opponent" work in Draw Something?

Tags: draw-something

In Draw Something, how does the "random opponent" feature work?

Is it completely random, or based off Facebook friends/detected location etc?

Comment: Don't think we can get any definitive answer without knowledge of the source code, which is unlikely to be available. We could try to  infer patterns but I don't think that's good enough for this site. In my experience, it's always been against random people (strangers).

Answer (score 0):

It isn't completely random.

It will find people around you and sometimes it finds people from random places :-D

Comment: That sounds completely random.